# High availability design of Azure eventhub/service bus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure eventhub in our azure based platform. 
What I plan to do is to create one event hub endpoint for publisher like:

Endpoint=sb://myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;....

And several consumer will read events from the event hub.

My biggest concern is the high availability of the event hub. How can I make sure that the event hub is always available for publisher & consumer?

Is it possible to have a master/slave event hub design so that when master fails, the slave could be elected as master to serve the publisher/consumer?

Comment: Wel, according to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/service-bus/v1_0/ the availability is 99.9%. Events are persisted so consumers will be able to catch up once it is up again. I don't know about the publishers.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same approach as you would with Service Bus messaging. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-outages-disasters/#protecting-queues-and-topics-against-datacenter-outages-or-disasters

You could either use and active-active model, or an active-passive model. Unfortunately at this point, Event Hubs does not do this for you, so you would have to implement some logic to failover to the secondary event hub (both publishers and consumers).

Comment: @Youxu - was this helpful?

Comment: ok, so seems I have to build my own logic to handle this scenario.